# OpenCV build to java, not generating a java folder in build

Tags: java, opencv, intellij-idea, cmake

I am trying to build OpenCV from source to `.jar`, since I need to have some contributed libs like Aruco (and these do not come with the default download from [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/releases.html).

Following a [tutorial](http://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/01-installing-opencv-for-java.html#install-opencv-3-x-under-linux), I set up CMake, and configuring gives the following (pieces of) output:

```
OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dpm face features2d flann fuzzy hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc java java_bindings_generator line_descriptor ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python_bindings_generator reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking ts video videoio videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
    Disabled:                    js python3 world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 cnn_3dobj cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev cvv dnn_modern freetype hdf matlab ovis python2 python2 sfm viz
    Applications:                perf_tests apps
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         YES


...

Java:                          
    ant:                         C:/opencv-3.4.1/apache-ant-1.10.5-bin/bin/ant.bat (ver 1.8.0)
    JNI:                         C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_171/include C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_171/include/win32 C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_171/include
    Java wrappers:               YES
    Java tests:                  NO
```

Then after I run `mingw32-make` in the build folder configured by CMake, it builds without errors. Then in the `build/bin` folder I do find the `opencv-341.jar` file as expected.

When I link this library in my IntelliJ IDEA, the modules like `org.opencv.aruco` are recognised, as expected. However when trying to build the java project, I get this error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)

Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java341 in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
at AraInvaders.Main.main(Main.java:24)
... 11 more
```

After some research I figured that I forgot to link the native library location, as was also described in the tutorial. However according to that tutorial (and other resources), the build should include a `build/java/x64` folder, containing a `.dll` file, however there is no `build/java` folder at all.

I do find a `libopencv_java341.dll` in `build/lib` however, linking that file does not resolve the problem. [Image showing that .dll file is linked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cs5uE.png)

When I download the Windows package form OpenCV, there is a Java folder in the build folder, and that does include the `.jar` file and an `/x64` folder, however, those do not include the contributed libs, so that is why I am trying to build from source.

So the question is, what should I do to correctly setup the OpenCV library, including the contributed libs?

Comment: Good point, I removed that tag!

Answer (score 0):

I asked on OpenCV forum http://answers.opencv.org/question/210451/opencv-401-face-module-for-java/.

So there are two solutions:

1. Since you built dynamically OpenCV libs, `opencv_java.dll` depends on `opencv_core.dll`, `opencv_imgproc.dll`, etc... you have to append the folder containing those to your system's PATH
2. Turn off `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` flag and build everything again.

Answer (score 0):

I renamed the generated dll from `libopencv_java412.dll` to `opencv_java412.dll` and it resolved the problem of library path problem ("`UnsatisfiedLinkError`").

The 412 in the file name is because I'm using OpenCV 4.1.2.